# How to rotate the axis labels on echarts4r radar chart?

Tags: r, echarts4r

### Reproducible example:

```
library(echarts4r)

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  Category = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Value = c(80, 50, 60, 70, 40)
)

# Creating a radar chart
e_charts(data, Category) |> 
  e_radar(Value)
```

I tried following with no rotation in the labels A, B, ..., E:

```
e_charts(data, Category) |> 
  e_radar(Value) |> 
  e_radar_opts(
    axisLabel = list(
      rotate = 45
    )
  )
```

Comment: Do you want to just change the orientation of the labels text by 45 degrees, or rotate the whole chart by 45 degrees? (I'm not sure either is possible, though!)

Comment: @AndrewGustar Orientation of labels only.